# How to toggle form element visibility in Play framework 2.0?

Tags: html, scala, playframework-2.0

For example I have some form which looks like this:

```
@main{
    <fieldset>
    @inputText(myForm"Id"),'_label -> "Id")
    @checkbox(myForm("isEnabled"))
    @inputText(myForm("someOptionvalue"))
    </fieldset>
}
```

What I need is that if isEnabled is checked - someOptionValue inputText should be shown. 
This checkbox is just an example and it can be any other element. I want to know how to show\hide elements depending on other elements. Sorry for my bad English. I hope somebody can help.

**add** I think  I should use java script but i don't know how inject js functions in play view templates

Answer (score 0):

The Play's form elements you used are Play Scala templates used to generate plain html.

For your purposes I think you should just use javascript the way you would any html form. An example would be:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  window.onload = function(e) {
    document.getElementById("myCheck").onclick = function() { 
      showHideElement();
    };
    showHideElement();
  }

  function showHideElement() {
    var checked = document.getElementById("myCheck").checked;
    var el = document.getElementById("myOptionValue");
    if (checked) {
      el.style.display = 'block'
    } else {
      el.style.display = 'none'
    }
  }
</script>
```

Your checkbox and input text template should both have id attributes added to them, example:

```
  @checkbox(myForm("isEnabled"), 'id -> "myCheck")
  @inputText(myForm("someOptionvalue"), 'id -> "myOptionValue")
```

Just for info you could add more attributes to the tags above like CSS style class, example:

```
@inputText(myForm("name"), 
'id -> "username", 
'class -> "classForInputText",
'_id -> "idForTheTopDlElement",
'_class -> "classForTheTopElement",
'size -> 30
)
```

You can then set the display to none or block